# How to get Response of REST API in JSON format by Default in Magento

Tags: magento, oauth, oauth-2.0, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

In magento as we use the REST url to access the data,as  `http://localhost/magemto/api/rest/products` it returns in XML format.

But as my team requirement, I should send the data in JSON format to access AJAX calls easily.. I have used REST client to include a header as 'Content-Type:appilcation/json'.. Then it returns in JSON format.. But I want it as defaultly by the magento API..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hey, I do have a solution for this, I would like to share with you.

First go to your magento root folder then go to following path

`\app\code\core\Mage\Api2\Model\Request.php`

Go  to the method getAccepTypes() and change with this code below it will fulfill your requirement.

```
public function getAcceptTypes()
{
    $qualityToTypes = array();
    $orderedTypes   = array();

    foreach (preg_split('/,\s*/', $this->getHeader('Accept')) as $definition) {
        $typeWithQ = explode(';', $definition);
        $mimeType  = trim(array_shift($typeWithQ));

        // check MIME type validity
        if (!preg_match('~^([0-9a-z*+\-]+)(?:/([0-9a-z*+\-\.]+))?$~i', $mimeType)) {
            continue;
        }
        $quality = '1.0'; // default value for quality

        if ($typeWithQ) {
            $qAndValue = explode('=', $typeWithQ[0]);

            if (2 == count($qAndValue)) {
                $quality = $qAndValue[1];
            }
        }
        $qualityToTypes[$quality][$mimeType] = true;
    }
    krsort($qualityToTypes);

    foreach ($qualityToTypes as $typeList) {
        $orderedTypes += $typeList;
    }

    unset($orderedTypes);
    $orderedTypes=Array
        ("application/json" => 1);

    return array_keys($orderedTypes);
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: I wound like to override this to local folder that would be best as this is not a good practice.

Comment: I have tested this and it is working fine in magento version 1.7.0.2

Comment: But did u mean to move this request.php file to local folder in app/core/code/local??

Comment: Yes search google how to override magento model class , you can find there, actually there are two ways, search you  will get many post related to this

Comment: the data is shown in browser page but it is not rendering for AJAX call. I think this is a cross-domain problem..

Comment: I think this solution doesn't set JSON as default, but as only response format. So XML responses will not be possible at all ..