# Magento custom REST API response in JSON

Tags: php, api, rest, magento, magento-1.9

For Magento 1.9 I'm working on a module where I defined a custom REST route to retrieve all categories with subcategories. When I call `<MAGE>/api/rest/eoarestapi/categories?type=rest` the function `_retrieveCollection()` from the class `Namespace_Restapi_Model_Api2_Category_Rest_Guest_V1` is being called. So far so good.

Now I am having the problem, that it returns the response in XML only and when I set the header explicitly to `Accept: application/json`, then I get the error **406 Not Acceptable** *An appropriate representation of the requested resource /api/rest/products could not be found on this server. Available variants: api.php , type application/x-httpd-php*

This seems very strange to me as I can remember having worked with JSON response back in Magento 1.8.

As a fix I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066963/how-to-get-response-of-rest-api-in-json-format-by-default-in-magento) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511858/response-of-rest-api-in-json-format) solution to retrieve JSON which works, but it doesn't seem to be a nice solution as it looks like it disables XML response completely.

Is there a better way to enable JSON output from the REST API in Magento 1.9?
Does anybody have some background knowledge on this?

Answer (score 1):

First I defined **@return mixed** in my API interface

and than in your model I do this

```
 $response = ['success' => 'ok', 'message' => 'json format'];
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($response); exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by overriding my request model. My Steps are following:

**1:Declare new module : Create app/etc/modules/Custom_RestJson.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Custom_RestJson>
<active>true</active>
<codePool>local</codePool>
</Custom_RestJson>
</modules>
</config>
```

**2. Create /app/code/local/Custom/RestJson/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Custom_RestJson>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</Custom_RestJson>
</modules>
<global>
<models>
<Custom_RestJson>
<class>Custom_RestJson_Model</class>
</Custom_RestJson>
<api2>
<rewrite>
<request>Core_Mage_Api2_Model_Request</request>
</rewrite>
</api2>
</models>
</global>
</config>
```

**3. Create /app/code/local/Custom/RestJson/Model/Api2/Request.php**

```
<?php
class Custom_RestJson_Model_Api2_Request extends Mage_Api2_Model_Request{

public function getAcceptTypes()
{
$qualityToTypes = array();
$orderedTypes = array();

foreach (preg_split('/,\s*/', $this->getHeader('Accept')) as $definition) {
$typeWithQ = explode(';', $definition);
$mimeType = trim(array_shift($typeWithQ));

// check MIME type validity
if (!preg_match('~^([0-9a-z*+\-]+)(?:/([0-9a-z*+\-\.]+))?$~i', $mimeType)) {
continue;
}
$quality = '1.0'; // default value for quality

if ($typeWithQ) {
$qAndValue = explode('=', $typeWithQ[0]);

if (2 == count($qAndValue)) {
$quality = $qAndValue[1];
}
}
$qualityToTypes[$quality][$mimeType] = true;
}
krsort($qualityToTypes);

foreach ($qualityToTypes as $typeList) {
$orderedTypes += $typeList;
}

return array_keys(array("application/json" => 1));
}

}
```